# Exception thrown by Facebook API call

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Using this code:

```
try
   {
    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
            array(
              'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/carlosnewtest',
              'message' => $_SESSION['current_user']['name']." ha comenzado a jugar Snow Punch!!",
             ));        
  }catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        $e_type = $e->getType();
        echo '<script>alert("SESSION "+'.$e_type.');</script>';
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($permission);
        echo("<script> top.location.href='".$loginUrl ."'</script>");
    }
```

...always throws an exception.

Comment: What error code do you receive?

Comment: Yes, the details of the exception would be most helpful.

Comment: Also, please include the package you are using to interface with the API as a tag.

Comment: the alert doesn't show me the error, is empty I try with e->getMessage() but is empty

Comment: Something is wrong then, if an exception was thrown, there should be a message to go with it. You might want to make sure the $_SESSION var is populated, if empty I could see FB throwing an exception for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try** switching `carlosnewtest` with the numeric `APP_ID` provided by Facebook.

Also, the Exception message is empty because <strike>you are never throwing it a message</strike> Facebook is not throwing a message [hat tip @Chris]  When using `try/catch` blocks, using [throw](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.throw.php) to specify what's put into your Exception message is very useful for debugging.

Comment: If an exception occurs in a try...catch block, the developer does not throw the exception, the exception is caused by a problem in the code.

Comment: @Chris Yes.  My point is that error handling in this situation is such that no Exception is being thrown with a message.  I believe that PHP defaults to an Exception code of '0' and a blank message, but I could be wrong.  Additionally, I see we're trying to catch a FacebookApiException here, so again I might be wrong.  If that's the case, I'll withdraw my answer once this question is resolved.

Comment: I'm saying that if the code in the catch block is being executed, that means there was an exception caused by a problem in the code. The OP states that the catch block is executing, meaning that there IS an exception. `throw` is totally irrelevant to the problem. The empty message is most likely a result of poor design in  `FacebookApiException` - also not the OP's problem or fault.

Comment: @Chris I've revised my answer to emphasize my actual suggestion for solving the OP's problem and de-emphasize what was meant as a passing observation about the use of `try/catch` without `throw`ing.  It should be clearer now.

Comment: ty problem solved! i had a problem in my code... I had to clear cache and done!

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoBlancoVivas Congrats.  Please add your fix as an answer and mark is as accepted when you are able.  This will let others learn from your success.  Cheers~